# How can I check if a streaming link is alive in android

Tags: java, android, rtmp, wowza

I am playing live streaming in android app. Streaming url is like `rtmp://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxx/AppName/test` , I am using wowza server for live streaming.  Is there any way to check if the url is still playing a stream or not .

Comment: did you got answer? i have same question

Comment: @NaXir not yet :(

Comment: Wowza cloud REST API is there. Might it can help via some webserivce etc?

Comment: didn't try that yet

Comment: Any news on this metter? I also need to check if a stream is online. But I don´t use wowza engine